# Query in project

Tags: smartcard

I'm a final year eng student. I've decided to do my final project in smart cards.

I want to know whether the smart card's can be used for our personal identification.

For example: it contains of our

1. personal/contact detail's
2. Driving licence info
3. PAN card detail's
4. Bank info
5. Passport detail etc and all the detail's which are required...

I want that card to be our proof. Now-a-day's ration card etc are being used as a proof.

I'm planning that all basic detail's which are considered as a proof for us it should be contained under a single card....... Is this can be implemented ? can you also say how it is?

At least say is my idea good or not.....

Answer (score 0):

The Australian government was looking at something like this a number of years ago , see an article here about it - http://www.smh.com.au/news/national/id-cards-to-foil-fraud-terrorism/2006/04/25/1145861349894.html

What you want to do is basically what they were doing but extending it to things like bank details etc, The real problem with an all in one card is security and if someone managed to get a hold or a a copy somehow they that is all the personal info they need for identify fraud / steal a persons money etc.

But as a final year project i think it would be a good thing to look at and see if it is feasible, could have alot of fun with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear.

Technically, smart cards can be used to store data (like different "details") and used for authentication (using strong cryptography) and this is exactly what has been done in many countries, like US [PIV/CAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Access_Card) or EU eID cards, like in [Estonia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estonian_ID_card), where it can be used to prove your driving capabilities or access online banking or vote on elections or travel to other EU countries.

In real life, a "single card to rule them all" will not happen any time soon, as there are several interested parties with different goals, requirements and (profit/lock-in) interests.